# How to call Invalidate() in custom control when a property of property that belongs to custom control?

Tags: c#, custom-controls, invalidation

I have a custom control progressbar that has a property that is an array of a class named `Bar`. I need to call Invalidate() function when property of this control's `Bar[i].Length` property has been changed. How can I do this?

my control is:

```
 public class SegmentedProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {
      ....

    public Bar[] Bars
    {
    get{return bars;}
    set
    {
    bars = value; 
    Invalidate();
    }
    }

    ....
    }
```

I need Invalidate() called automatically when `Bar.Length` changed

```
void ChangeBarLength()
{
   segmPBar.Bars[0].Length = 10;
}
```

**UPDATE: Bar class added**

```
public class Bar
{

    public Bar(long length, long start)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.start = start;
    }

    long length;
    long start;

    public long Start {
        get { return start; }

        set {
            start = value;
        }
    }
    public long Length {
        get { return length; }
        set { length = value; }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2: It worked using PropertyChanged event**

```
public long Length {
        get { return length; }
        set { 
            if(value != length && PropertyChanged!=null)
                PropertyChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty);
            length = value;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you override the Length property, or is there a PropertyChanged notification available for your Bar Class. We don't know what a Bar is.

Comment: I have added Bar class. I didn't mind to try using 'PropertyChanged'. Now I have implemented it and it worked. Thanks.